# Nginx - rewrite rule url encoding

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

Got a rewrite rule for nginx;

```
if ($query_string ~ "page=search&shift=1&reset=1&search=([^&]+)(&searchButton=Zoek)?"){
    set $search $1;
    rewrite ^/?$ https://$host/zoeken/$search/? permanent;
}
```

When the search query `hi/hi` is performed, the output of the URL is:
    `website.com/zoeken/hi/hi`, which returns a 404.

The expected outcome is `website.com/zoeken/hi%52hi/`

What is the correct rewrite rule to have the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that in nginx we can't turn off or on URL encoding.
We got a choice to install another module, http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSetMiscModule#set_escape_uri

But since we want to avoid installing modules, we set the rewrites rule in apache, rather than nginx.

Too bad.